# Laravel Gates and/or Policies

Tags: php, laravel

Right now Im thinking about implementing policies into my Project.
So I want 3 types of roles: User, Admin and Office.

I have a Customer class which has the following CRUD functions:

```
class CustomerController extends Controller
{

public function getAllCustomer()
{
    return Customer::get();
}

public function addNewCustomer(Request $request)
{
    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'Title' => 'required',
        'Name' => 'required|max:255',
        'Surname' => 'required|max:255',
        'Email' => 'required',
        'Phone' => 'required',
        'Password' => 'required',
        'dateofBirth' => 'required'
    ]);

    return \app\model\Customer::create($request->all());
}


public function update (Request $request , Customer $id)
{
    $id->update($request->all());
}


public function destroy (Customer $id)
{
    $id->delete();
}
```

What I want is that only the Admin should be able to use the CRUD functions for all the Customers. A User should only be able to use CRUD functions on his own data (so the Customer can only do it with his own data).

I read this article:
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/gates-and-policies-in-laravel--cms-29780

But I still don't know exactly how to implement it in my Project, and whether I should use Gates or policies (it seems like policies are easier, or?).

I would be very thankful if somebody could write me an example on how to implement it on my work.

Comment: have you read the official documentation? https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authorization

Comment: Yes, But i didnt find a solution for different role models.

Answer (score 2):

Create policies for each of your model. Bind policies to routes https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authorization#via-middleware

```
Route::post('/post/{post}', function () {
// The current user may edit post...
})->middleware('can:edit,post');
```

Create a parent policy which all the other policies will extend and add to it **before** method which will basically check if your user is admin and if so no further checking is needed.

```
public function before(User $authenticatedUser, $ability)
{
    // super admin can access everything
    if ($authenticatedUser->role == 'super_admin') {
        return true;
    }

    return null; //fall through to the policy method
}
```

Create a Post policy which will have **edit** permission check

```
class PostPolicy extends Policy
{

    public function edit(User $authenticatedUser, Post $post)
    {
        return $authenticatedUser->id == $post->author_id;
    }
}
```

The general idea, on how to work with policies is as simple as that.